# What checks should be performed on user data from forms?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm writing an app engine app, that has some input fields.

Are there any concerns I need to take into account about something like [this](http://xkcd.com/327/)?

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do with the data. You probably will need to sanitize it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should validate that any input from your users meets your requirements.  For example, if you need an positive integer, then make sure that's what you got.

As far as strings, you don't have to worry about SQL (or GQL in this case) injection as long as you don't construct the queries by hand.  Instead use the [`GqlQuery.bind()`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlqueryclass.html#GqlQuery_bind) method, or the methods provided by [`Query`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html) to pass the values (e.g., [`Query.filter()`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html#Query_filter)).  Then these classes will take care of formulating the query so you don't need to worry about the syntax (or injection).

Examples (adapted from the docs linked to previously):

```
# this basic string query is safe
query = Song.all()
query.filter('title =', self.request.get('title'))

# a GqlQuery version of the previous example
query = GqlQuery("SELECT x FROM Song WHERE title = :1",self.request.get('title'))

# sanitize/validate when you have requirements: e.g., year must be a number
query = Song.all()
try:
    year = int(self.request.get('year'))  # make sure we got a number
except:
    show error msg
query.filter('year =', year)
```

Comment: Even if you do construct the queries by hand, the worst a user can do is add more filters to your query; GQL only does SELECT and `;` doesn't do anything, so there's no risk of a Bobby Tables scenario.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of forms libraries that do most of the hard work for you - you should use one of them. [Django's newforms](http://django096docs.appspot.com/newforms.html) library is included with App Engine.